# No value for xxxxx in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In my class I have

```
data class Datum (
    val id: String,
    val amount: Long,
    val transport: Long,
    val total: Long,
    val weight: Long,
    val payment: String,
    val paymentID: Any? = null, // issue (it can have string value or be null when coming from server)
    val paymentMethod: Any? = null, //issue (it can have string value or be null when coming from server)
    val accepted: Long,
    val customer: Customer,
    val laundry: Laundry,
    val driver: Driver,
    val progresses: List<Progress>,
    val services: List<Servic>,
    val createdAt: String
)
```

Then in my fragment where I try to loop my data into list I get this error `No value for paymentID`

```
 fun getOrders(response: String, list: ArrayList<Datum>) {
    var jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
    val jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data")

    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
        val jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
        Log.d("3: ", jsonObject1.toString())

        var listingObject = Datum(
            jsonObject1.getString("id"),
            jsonObject1.getLong("amount"),
            jsonObject1.getLong("transport"),
            jsonObject1.getLong("total"),
            jsonObject1.getLong("weight"),
            jsonObject1.getString("payment"),
            jsonObject1.get("paymentID"), //here
            jsonObject1.get("paymentMethod"), //here
            jsonObject1.getLong("accepted"),
            jsonObject1.get("customer") as Customer,
            jsonObject1.get("laundry") as Laundry,
            jsonObject1.get("driver") as Driver,
            jsonObject1.get("progresses") as List<Progress>,
            jsonObject1.get("services") as List<Servic>,
            jsonObject1.getString("createdAt")
        )
        list.add(listingObject)
    }
}
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: well, do you have a paymentID field in your json ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have `payment_id` variable

Comment: i'm not asking about the variable, i'm asking if you have it in your json

Comment: I do have it in my json yes, but for my current data is null

Comment: @a_local_nobody this is my full code https://app.quicktype.io?share=Z53hD6J14iulUtXnlNjQ

Comment: `payment_id` is not the same as `paymentID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you might have created the sample `data` class using any converter, it assigns `null`  values to `Any?` by default as it does not have enough information.

Just replace `Any`? with `String?`

```
data class Datum (
    val id: String,
    val amount: Long,
    val transport: Long,
    val total: Long,
    val weight: Long,
    val payment: String,
    val paymentID: String? = null, 
    val paymentMethod: String? = null,
    val accepted: Long,
    val customer: Customer,
    val laundry: Laundry,
    val driver: Driver,
    val progresses: List<Progress>,
    val services: List<Servic>,
    val createdAt: String
)
```

**EDIT**

```
 fun getOrders(response: String): List<Datum> {
     val orders = Gson().fromJson(response, Orders::class.java)
     return orders.data
 }
```

Now at your caller, i.e in onResponse method

replace

```
val list: ArrayList<Datum> = ArrayList()
getOrders(response, list)
```

with

```
val list: ArrayList<Datum> =  getOrders(response)
```

Comment: now I get `org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to` on `jsonObject1.get("customer") as Customer,`

Comment: You need to do the same for deserializing other classes, better use some kind of json deserializer like gson or moshi

Comment: Gson I have but I'm not sure how to use it for this code :/

Comment: I have updated code to support gson

Comment: appreciate it and then `for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {` will stay the same as is now?

Comment: no you can remove everything, just use gson part of code

Comment: I have updated the answer for getOrders method

Comment: I think you forget that I had `list` in my function `getOrders(response: String, list: ArrayList<Datum>)` this list later will be returned to my main function which I place data into recycler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228197/discussion-between-rajan-kali-and-mafortis).